# How do I turn on assertions for Android Studio with Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, jvm, jvm-arguments

I cannot get `assert` to work under Android Studio 3.3.2 using Kotlin (Windows 10).

I've read/researched a bunch and this is what I've done:

**Help | Edit Custom VM Options...** at which point I was presented with a dialog saying *File 'C:\Users\me\.AndroidStudio3.3\config\studio64.exe.vmoptions' does not exist. Create?* so I clicked **[Create]**.

Next I'm editing the **studio64.exe.vmoptions** file. I add the line **-ea** and run the app (on a virtual device through the IDE). I am not getting any assertions. Whether I **Run 'app'** or **Debug 'app'** makes no difference.

My code:

```
//create tileViews
assert(tileViews.isEmpty(), { "04/19/2019 17:42" })
assert(!tileViews.isEmpty(), { "04/19/2019 17:42b" })
assert(7 < 5, { "04/19/2019 17:42c" })
Log.d("##","04/19/2019 17:42 (log)")
Toast.makeText(parent.context, "ruh roh!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

results in the `Toast` being displayed and the msg being sent to the logcat, but nothing else.

Note that at least one (I'd expect exactly two) of those `assert` conditions has to be false.

I even restarted Android Studio and ran/debugged the app again.

What am I missing/doing wrong here?

Also (and maybe this answers the above question): what should I actually see? Will it be a "splat" in the app? Something sent to the logcat? Something else entirely (which maybe it's doing and I'm simply unaware)?